# Java Swing: drawing not centered in separate JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, drawing, geometry

I'm Jari and I'm having some trouble with drawing a circle in a separate JPanel:
my circle won't center in the middle of a jpanel called "jPanelOutput" here 's my code:

```
Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) jPanelOutput.getGraphics().create();

    Insets insets = jPanelOutput.getInsets();
    System.out.println(insets.toString());
    int w = (int)((jPanelOutput.getWidth())/ 2)-insets.left-insets.right;
    int h = (int)(jPanelOutput.getHeight()/ 2)-insets.top-insets.bottom;
    System.out.println(w + "  " + h);
    graphics.translate(w, h);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
    graphics.drawOval(0, 0, 150, 150);
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    graphics.dispose();
```

But the output is:
[image]
don't worry about the spelling, it's in Dutch ("vlakke spiegel" means flat mirror and "cirkel" means circle. the title means fysics mirror laws.

thanks in advance
Jari

Comment: search here for getPreferredSIze, then all coordinates are from getHeight/Weight, carefully with swaping Height/Weight v.s. Weight/Height, because, seems like as your printscreen talking about ...

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Don't `getGraphics()`. "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()`…"—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the circle is drawn from the top_left corner. The upper left corner of the circle is at perfect center position. All you need to do is to subtract circle's width and height from the center point. 
 The following code will center the circle.

```
int cw = 150;
int ch = 150;
graphics.translate(w - cw / 2, h - ch / 2);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
graphics.drawOval(0, 0, cw, ch);
```